# Angular 6 communication child - parent with ng content

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a little problem with passing arguments from parent to child with ng-content.

I have a modal component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
})
export class ModalComponent {
  @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal: ModalDirective;

  constructor() {}

  show() { 
    this.childModal.show();
  }

  hide() {
    this.childModal.hide();
  }
}


// html
<div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-info">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <ng-content select=".modal-body"> </ng-content>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="hide()"> Cancel </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in my main component in html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  //some data
  <button (click)="myModal.show();">Show Modal</button>
</div>

<app-modal #myModal>
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
</app-modal>
```

And it works fine. When I need data in modal I just pass it to show method:

```
<button (click)="myModal.show(item);">Show Modal</button>
```

but I need to include another component in my modal:

```
<app-modal #myModal>
  <div class="modal-body"><another-app-component></another-app-component></div>
</app-modal>
```

And I have no idea how to pass 'item' data to this another-app-component

For example ngFor generates 5 items, each item will has his own data. And when I click on first 'Show Modal' I need to send data of the first item to another-app-component

Comment: use `@Input` in the child component??

Comment: But another-app-component including is out of ngFor, so I cannot access to specify item from ngFor

Comment: I don't understand.... is out of ngFor?

Comment: I have one modal for every items. And when I init modal I am out of scope of ngFor so I can't access items variable (with data)

Comment: I dont understand, just do this `<another-app-component item="item"></another-app-component>`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Please see again in post. modal is out of ngFor. So I don't have access to item. I want to one modal for every items instead one modal for one items because I could have a lot of items and I'm not sure if having a lot of modals is good for performance

Comment: are you using `ng-bootstrap`?

Comment: Yes I'm using ngx-bootstrap

Comment: Pass item from typescript and call myModel.show through typescript on button click